# Can switch use String.contains?

Tags: groovy

I'm trying to make this work, and it seems not to be accepted. Is there any fix, or workaround to it?

```
switch(email){
    case (email.contains('acceptall')):
        log.info email
        break
    default:
        log.info "Doesn't work!"    
}
```

I'm using groovy for a script in SoapUI

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use a regex, roughly:

```
switch (email) {
  case ~/.*acceptall.*/:
    log.info(email)
    break;
  default:
    log.info("Doesn't work!")
}
```

https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_switch_case

> Switch supports the following kinds of comparisons
>
> - Class case values matches if the switchValue is an instanceof the
>   class
> - Regular expression case value matches if the string of the
>   switch
> - Value matches the regex Collection case value matches if the
>   switch
> - Value is contained in the collection. This also includes ranges
>   too (since they are Lists)
> - if none of the above are used then the case
>   value matches if the case value equals the switch value

Answer (score 3):

you almost got it right, just need to turn it into a closure e.g.

```
switch (email) {
  case { it.contains('acceptall') }:
    log.info(email)
    break;
  default:
    log.info("Doesn't work!")
}
```

Comment: what is it?  [it explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54902509/what-is-the-groovy-it)

Comment: also, in a jenkins pipeline this will generate an error [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62210311/jenkins-shared-library-cpscallableinvocation)