# What is the Groovy 'it'?

Tags: groovy

I have a collection which I process with `removeIf {}` in Groovy. Inside the block, I have access to some `it` identifier. What is this and where is it documented?

Comment: http://groovy-lang.org/closures.html#implicit-it

Answer (score 30):

`it` is an implicit variable that is provided in closures. It's available when the closure doesn't have an explicitly declared parameter.

When the closure is used with collection methods, such as `removeIf`, `it` will point to the current iteration item.

It's like you declared this:

```
List<Integer> integers = [1, 2, 3]
for(Integer it: integers) {print(it)}
```

When you use `each`, instead (and that's an example), you can get `it` implicitly provided:

```
integers.each{print(it)} //it is given by default
```

Or

```
integers.removeIf{it % 2 == 0} //it is the argument to Predicate.test()
```

`it` will successively take the values `1`, `2`, and `3` as iterations go.

You can, of course, rename the variable by declaring the parameter in the closure:

```
integers.each{myInteger -> print(myInteger)}
```

In this case, Groovy doesn't supply the implicit `it` variable. [The documentation](http://groovy-lang.org/closures.html#implicit-it) has more details

Comment: There's nothing about `it` that's specific to iterating collections

Comment: @Dónal Agreed, I was just reading through the answer and realized that needed to be edited. Thanks

Comment: `Iterator`, its a kind of pointer to the actual item in the collection during the loop - iteration over

Answer (score 9):

If you create a closure without an explicit argument list, it defaults to having a single argument named `it`. Here's an example that can be run in the Groovy console

```
Closure incrementBy4 = { it + 4 }

// test it
assert incrementBy4(6) == 10
```

In the example above the closure is identical to

```
Closure incrementBy4 = { it -> it + 4 }
```

Here's another example that uses `removeIf`

```
Closure remove2 = { it == 2 }

def numbers = [1, 2, 3]
numbers.removeIf(remove2)

// verify that it worked as expected
assert numbers == [1, 2]
```

Comment: to complete the answer a bit: {} has the the implicit variable "it". {x->} has no implicit "it" variable, but an explicit "x". {->} has not implicit "it" variable and no explicit variable.