# Jenkins shared library, CpsCallableInvocation

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to create a shared library for Jenkins.

I tried to create a script to send notifications through Teams, this is the code:

```
def call(String buildStatus = null, String webook) {
    def status
    def color

    switch(buildStatus) {
        case { null || "SUCCESS" }:
            status = "Success"
            color = "Green"
            break
        case "FAILED":
            status = "Failed"
            color = "Red"
            break
        default:
            status = null
            color = null
    }

    println(status + " " + color)
}
```

The problem is that if I try to run it in my pipeline I get this exception:

```
Error when executing always post condition:
CpsCallableInvocation{methodName=call, call=com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CpsClosureDef@1ba818f1, receiver=org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2@22438c5c, arguments=[SUCCESS]}
```

This is the pipeline I am testing:

```
pipeline{
    agent{
        label 'linux'
    } 

    stages{
        stage('Build') {   
            steps{    
                ...snip...
            }
        }

    }
    post {
        always {
            notifyTeams(currentBuild.result, "XXXXX")
        }
    }    

}
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is caused by the closure used in the switch statement. Jenkins transforms every closure into CPS-transformed closures, which are different than the regular Groovy closures. There are multiple use cases where using CPS-transformed closures causes unexpected errors. I guess this use case was not documented yet, and the closest one to yours is [using closure inside the `GString` one](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/cps-method-mismatches/#PipelineCPSmethodmismatches-ClosuresinsideGString).

There are two ways to solve it. Firstly, you can replace a closure in the switch statement with regular values, e.g.:

```groovy
def call(String buildStatus = null, String webook) {
    def status
    def color

    switch(buildStatus) {
        case null:
            status = "Success"
            color = "Green"
            break
        case "SUCCESS":
            status = "Success"
            color = "Green"
            break
        case "FAILED":
            status = "Failed"
            color = "Red"
            break
        default:
            status = null
            color = null
    }

    println(status + " " + color)
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to use closure inside the switch statement, you will need to extract the `switch` block to a separate method annotated with `@NonCPS`. This is the instruction for the `groovy-cps` to not transform the code inside this method. (You could annotate the `call` method with `@NonCPS`, however, if you plan to use pipeline steps in it, it won't work. Pipeline steps have to be executed in the cps mode.)

```groovy
def call(String buildStatus = null, String webook) {
    def (status, color) = switchBuildStatusAndColor(buildStatus)

    println(status + " " + color)
}

@NonCPS
private static switchBuildStatusAndColor(String buildStatus) {
    switch (buildStatus) {
        case { null || "SUCCESS" }:
            return ["Success", "Green"]

        case "FAILED":
            return ["Failed", "Red"]
    }

    return [null, null]
}
```

Comment: It worked perfectly, thank you very much! And  thanks for the explanation, now everything is much clearer to me!

Comment: I had the exact same problem and this change worked for me as well! You're a lifesaver @Szymon!